# can't update siblings in HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<td>
    <select tabindex="1" id="global_location_id" name="global_location_id">
      <option value="0">-- NONE --</option>
      <option value="15" style="font-weight: bold">canada</option>
      <option value="16" style="font-weight: bold">usa</option>    
    </select>
    <input tabindex="1" id="location_id" name="location_id" value="15" type="hidden">
</td>
```

When the item in the drop down list changes, I want to save the value in a hidden field... that's a sibling to the drop down. 
I have the following jquery code:

```
    $("body").live("change", "#global_location_id", function(e){
            console.log(e);
            var list = e.target;
            var selected_location_value = $(list).val();
            console.log(selected_location_value);
            //save this value in the sibling <input> box called name=location_id
             $(this).siblings("#location_id").attr('value',selected_location_value);
      });
```

I must have a syntax error somewhere because this code is not working.  Specifically, it's the line that attempts to save to the hidden input field called location_id that is not updating.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.
Thanks.

Comment: if jQuery version is newer than 1.8 , `live()` has been deprecated for years and was removed from the api

Comment: I know it's old but this is an open source app... have to get the guys upstream to change something big like that.  i'm just tweaking for a bug that is urgent.  thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
I had to replace

```
$(this).siblings("#location_id").attr('value',selected_location_value)
```

with

```
$(list).siblings("#location_id").attr('value',selected_location_value)
```

Comment: You mean `$(this)` in your first (uncorrected) part, right?

Comment: no need for `siblings()` ... ID's are unique in a page, just use the id as selector

Comment: @dot What is the difference between those two lines of code?

Comment: @VincentWilkie sorry, typo.

Comment: @PaulRoub, yes. my bad.

Comment: @dot don't forget to accept your answer, as it might help someone else out :3

Comment: @VincentWilkie ok thanks.  It says I have to wait 2 days before I can accept the answer... :/

Comment: Quite honestly I don't see how your answer actually made any difference either. Looking closer the use of `live()` is incorrect. `live()` doesn't have the same signature as `on()` and code should really be `$('"#global_location_id').live('change'....`

Comment: @charlietfl that's because there's a bigger picture to the code... i only included what was necessary to troubleshoot the problem.